# Sequence and series. What is $b_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> 5. (a) If $a,b$ are positive quantities such that $(a<b)$ and if 
>      $a_1 = \frac{a+b}{2}$, $b_1 = \sqrt{a_1b}$, $a_2 = \frac{a_1+b_1}{2}$, $b_2 = \sqrt{a_2b_1},\dotsc, a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}}{2}$, $b_n=\sqrt{a_nb_{n-1}},\dotsc$ then show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n = \frac{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}{\cos^{-1}\frac{a}{b}}$.

Please give me hints so that i can solve it..I am stuck...

I found that $b_n=\frac {1}{2}\sqrt{a_{n-2}b_{n-1}+a_{n-2}b_{n-2}+b_{n-2}b_{n-1}+a_{n-2}b_{n-3}}$

Now i m stuck...cant understand what to do

Comment: $b_n$ is $N$th Bernoulli number.

Comment: Please type out images. Formatting tips [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you @Professor Vector .. your suggestions helped me to solve this

Comment: Thank you  @Claude Leibovici... your suggestions helped me to solve this

Comment: I was initially doing wrong